# ngtemplateoutlet inside two different loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to repeat the same code in two different places.profile1 
     and profile2 are  arrays. i want repeat same html code without duplicate them

```
   profile1 = [{name : 'mr.A1',age : 25  },
                {name : 'mr.B1',age : 23}];
   profile2 = [{name : 'mr.A2',age : 25  },
                {name : 'mr.B2',age : 23}];


      <ng-container *ngFor="let x of profile1">
      <ng-template #templateRef>
       <p> {{x.name}}</p>
      <p> {{x.age}}</p>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef"></ng-template>
      </ng-container>

     // above code shows the result
      mr.A1
      25
      mr.B1
      23

      // below code shows nothing

    <ng-container *ngFor="let x of profile2">
     <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef"></ng-template>
    </ng-container>

    // i want following results using ngTemplateOutlet
      mr.A2
      25
      mr.B2
      23
```

Comment: Can you share in stackbiltz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of dynamic behavior is best for custom components.

But if you want to pursue this way, know that you have to use a `ngTemplateOutletContext` to send data to your template references.

This is done like this :

```html
<ng-template #profile let-person>
  <div>
    {{ person?.name }} is {{ person?.age }} years old.
  </div>
</ng-template>

<h1>First batch</h1>

<ng-container *ngFor="let person of profiles">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="profile; context: { $implicit: person }"></ng-container>
</ng-container>

<h1>Second batch</h1>

<ng-container *ngFor="let person of profiles">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="profile; context: { $implicit: person }"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3jpj4) - [Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)